# Automatic Retrieval of Streamed URL after AWS HLS Streaming

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, http-live-streaming, aws-media-convert

I have set up an on-demand video service in AWS. After uploading a video to the S3 input bucket, a Lambda function is automatically triggered, which does HLS streaming with the object to a specific folder in the output bucket. Already i have created cloudfront distribution. I want to retrieve the streamed URL from the output S3 bucket and receive a notification, So that i can then update the streammed URL in my mongoDb database ?

I want to retrieve the specific streamed URL from the output S3 bucket automatically as soon as the lambda function finishes the HLS streaming .What would be best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do it, you are basically looking service that can subscribe to S3 event notifications for example SQS, SNS, Lambda function etc.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations.html#supported-notification-event-types
I would suggest lambda, you can update the DB table with URL in the lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me; I attempted to deploy a VOD solution template on a test demo, and I received an HLS url in my email from SNS, but in the app itself. I wonder too where to find hls url and automatically retrieve it to my app.

[VOD publishing workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELO3C.png)

I wonder can we edit lambda in this process so it will update my DBS too ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally DID it!, the way I do it is by using the Lambda function to subscribe to the SNS events topic.

here what my lambda look like.

```
const mutationUpdateURL = `
  mutation UpdateCourseModuleURL($id: ID!, $source_url: String!) {
    updateCourseModules(input: {id: $id, source_url: $source_url}) {
      id
      source_url
    }
  }
`;

// This helper function will extract the CourseModuleID from the given hlsURL
const extractCourseModuleID = (hlsUrl) => {
  const regex = /\/([a-f0-9\-]+)_[^/]+\.m3u8$/;
  const match = hlsUrl.match(regex);
  return match ? match[1] : null;
};

export const handler = async (event) => {
  // Extract HLS URL from the event object
  const snsMessageStr = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].Sns.Message);
  const hlsUrl = snsMessageStr.Outputs.HLS_GROUP[0];

  // console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
  // console.log(`ENDPOINT: ${GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT}`);
  // console.log(`API_KEY: ${GRAPHQL_API_KEY}`);
  console.log(`hlsUrl: ${hlsUrl}`);

  // Extract CourseModuleID from hlsURL
  const courseModuleId = extractCourseModuleID(hlsUrl);
  if (!courseModuleId) {
    console.error('Failed to extract CourseModuleID from hlsURL:', hlsUrl);
    return { statusCode: 400, body: 'Failed to extract CourseModuleID' };
  }
  console.log(`course Module Id: ${courseModuleId}`);

  const endpoint = new URL(GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT);

  const signer = new SignatureV4({
    credentials: defaultProvider(),
    region: AWS_REGION,
    service: 'appsync',
    sha256: Sha256
  });

  const body = JSON.stringify({
    mutationUpdateURL, 
    variables: {
      id: courseModuleId,
      source_url: hlsUrl
    }
  });

  const mutationBody = JSON.stringify({
    query: mutationUpdateURL,
    variables: {
        id: courseModuleId,
        source_url: hlsUrl
    }
  });

  const requestToBeSigned = new HttpRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "x-api-key": GRAPHQL_API_KEY,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      host: endpoint.host
    },
    hostname: endpoint.host,
    body: mutationBody,
    path: endpoint.pathname
  });

  const signed = await signer.sign(requestToBeSigned);
  const request = new Request(endpoint, signed);

  let statusCode = 200;
  let response;
  let responseBody;

  try {
    response = await fetch(request);
    responseBody = await response.json();
    console.log(responseBody);
    if (responseBody.errors) {
      statusCode = 400;
      console.error('GraphQL Errors:', responseBody.errors);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    statusCode = 500;
    responseBody = {
      errors: [
        {
          message: error.message
        }
      ]
    };
    console.error('Fetching Error:', error.message);
  }

  return {
    statusCode,
    // Uncomment below to enable CORS requests
    // headers: {
    //   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    //   "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"
    // },
    body: JSON.stringify(responseBody)
  };
};
```

Notice the name of the vids file I have to rename the vids module to "moduleId_filename.mp4" so we can just get the `moduleId` back from SNS and than save it to DynamoDB with the correct order and `moduleId`